# Javascript Preloading images on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, preloader

My preloader seems unstable on iPad, even though it works perfectly in all major browsers on both PC and MAC.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it don't, but if I clear the cache, it allmost allways fails on first try.. I'm really stuck here, so any help would be appreciated!

This is my code:

```
    function preloadimages(arr){

    var newimages=[], loadedimages=0
    var postaction=function(){}
    var arr=(typeof arr!="object")? [arr] : arr
    function imageloadpost(){
        loadedimages++
        if (loadedimages==arr.length){
            postaction(newimages) //call postaction and pass in newimages array as parameter
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        newimages[i]=new Image()
        newimages[i].src=arr[i]
        newimages[i].onload=function(){
            imageloadpost()
        }
        newimages[i].onerror=function(){
            imageloadpost()
        }
    }
    return { //return blank object with done() method
        done:function(f){
            postaction=f || postaction //remember user defined callback functions to be called when images load
        }
    }
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

    preloadimages(['img/bg_joejuice.jpg',
                    'img/bg_facebook.jpg',
                    'img/bg_webshop.jpg',
                    'img/bg_spotify.jpg',
                    'img/btn_grey_down.png',
                    'img/btn_pink_down.png',
                    'img/coffee_active.png',
                    'img/juice_normal.png',
                    'img/sandwich_active.png',
                    'img/remove_down.png',
                    'img/inc_down.png',
                    'img/dec_down.png',
                    'img/checkbox_unchecked.png',
                    'img/hide_spotify.png',
                    'img/logo_facebook_active.png',
                    'img/logo_joejuice.png',
                    'img/logo_spotify_active.png',
                    'img/logo_webshop_active.png',
                    'img/checkbox_unchecked.png',]
    ).done(function(){
        console.log("loaded");
    });
});
```

EDIT:
Sorry for not specifying..

I get no errors in console (related), and it doesn't get to the point where it logs the "loaded" comment.

http://md4a1215.keaweb.dk

NEW EDIT
I got 19 pictures. It runs the forloop 19 times. When the error occur, I usually get 18 "onload" (but has seen as low as 16) and never any "onerror".

It looks like it's the onerror function that isn't triggered (allthough it DOES trigger i all major browsers on both MAC and PC, and it does trigger on the iPad if I just remove one of the images thst id included in the list).. Does this sound right? - And if it does, how can I get this to work?

Comment: How does it fail? What is the problem?

Comment: This is probably not the cause of the problem, but all ; between statements are missing. I've already seen that causing issues on some browsers. JavaScript is supposed to be tolerant to that, but it's can't hurt to be cautious about that.

Comment: Can you add logs everywhere to see precisely where things go wrong ?

Comment: looks like the - if (loadedimages==arr.length){ - never fires, but i get no - newimages[i].onerror=function(){ - , only alot of - newimages[i].onload=function(){ -

Comment: As described in the new edit, it looks like something is wrong with the onerror function..

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to increment loadedimages onerror as well as onload.  Try something like this (this retries the preload on error, and skips the image if it fails maxattempts times)

```
function preloadimages(arr) { 
    var newimages = [], loadedimages=0, attempts = 0, maxattempts = 5;
    var postaction=function(){}; 
    var arr=(typeof arr!='object') ? [arr] : arr; 
    function imageloadpost(){ 
        if (loadedimages == newimages.length){ console.log('Preloading of images complete. Loaded ' + newimages.length + ' images of ' + arr.length + '. Processing postaction.'); postaction(newimages); } 
    } 
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ 
        newimages[i]=new Image(); 
        newimages[i].src=arr[i]; 
        newimages[i].onload=function(){ 
            console.log('Loaded ' + loadedimages + ' ' + this.src); 
            attempts=0; 
            loadedimages++;  
            imageloadpost(); 
        }; 
        newimages[i].onerror=function(){ 
            attempts++; 
            if(attempts < maxattempts){ 
                console.log('Failed to load: ' + this.src + ' trying again'); 
                this.src = this.src; 
            } 
            else{ 
                console.log('Skipping ' + this.src); 
                var tSrc = this.src;                
                var thisIndex = -1;
                for(var i=0; i <arr.length; i++)
                {
                    if(newimages[i].src === tSrc)
                    {
                        thisIndex = i;
                    }
                }
                attempts=0; 
                if(thisIndex >= 0)
                {
                    console.log('Removing ' + tSrc + ' from image list due to failure to load.');
                    newimages.splice(thisIndex,1);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Error encountered, could not find ' + tSrc + ' in newimages.');
                    loadedimages++;
                }
                imageloadpost(); 
            } 
        };
    }  //end of for loop
    return { done: function(f) { postaction = f || postaction } } 
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    preloadimages(['img/image1.jpg','img/image2.jpg','img/image3.jpg']).done(function() { console.log('Function preloadimages is done'); });
});
```